# Running a function after async operation is complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm banging my head against the wall to figure out how to push data that is being written on file asynchronously into an array. Writing the data synchronously (and checking if the item is the last on the list) takes too much time so I decided to make it run async. After doing some research, it seems that I could use a callback

I would prefer not to use an external library for doing this, since I'm pretty sure either a callback or a Promise should do the trick. Thanks!

```
//Iterate through list and make HTTP request to get data
dataDocument.map(function(item, index) {

    request(item, function(err, res, html) {
        if (err) throw err;
        renderData(html, item);
    });

});

//Renders data 
function renderData(html, item) {
    ...some calculations here.

    writeData(output, id, function() {
        pushed(output);
    });
};

//Writes the data on file
function writeData(output, id) {
    fs.appendFile('./output.json', output);

//SHOULD I USE A CALLBACK HERE TO PUSH INTO AN ARRAY ONCE IT'S COMPLETE?

};

//NEED HELP HERE: Pushed the data into an array and eliminates last comma.
function pushed(data) {
   var arr = [];
   arr.push(data);
}
```

Comment: Do not understand 'checking if the item is the last on the list) takes too much time so I decided to make it run async'. Can you basically describe the work flow of this data process?

Comment: You can't generally just decide to make something async.  The underlying operation either is or isn't async.  Adding an item to an array is certainly not async by itself.  `fs.appendFile()` is async by itself.  Really not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Unclear question as it stands now.  Please clarify with more detials for what you're trying to do.  And, please use text in your question, not only comments in your code.

Comment: Return promise and concatenates `.then` to make a cascade of promises, which will be called in an iterative way.

Answer (score 0):

With promises it will look cleaner and leaner. Promisify all the involved functions, and use `Promise.all` to know when you have collected all data:

```
// Promisify all the involved callback-based functions:
function promiseRequest(item) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(item, function (err, res, html) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(html);
            }
        })
    })
}

//Renders data 
function promiseRenderData(html, item) {
    //...some calculations here.
    return promiseWriteData(output, id).then(function() {
        return output;
    });
};

//Writes the data on file
function promiseWriteData(output, id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.appendFile('./output.json', output, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

//Iterate through list and make HTTP request to get data
Promise.all(dataDocument.map(function(item, index) {
    return promiseRequest(item).then(function(html) {
        return promiseRenderData(html, item);
    };
})).then(function(arr) {
    // Do something with `arr` here
});
```